# Unable to reflectively alter field inside Spring Controller in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, reflection

My senior developer and I hit this weird problem yesterday trying to test a Spring controller with a mocked service. We are not using Mockito as this is a legacy system that we can't be bothered adding Mockito too.

The strangeness began when we attempted to use Reflection to change the `@Autowired` service instance that was contained within the Controller after the application context was created.

We tried to use `ReflectionUtils`, `ReflectionTestUtils` and just vanilla reflection but the instance of the class would not change at all. We confirmed that the reflection was making the field accessable, because it is a private field (using `field.isAccessible()` before and after the `field.setAccessible(true)`, but the instance ID refused to change. This was confirmed multiple times by checking the instance using `toString()` and also `println()` statements in both the mocked and genuine services.

I'll post the code below:

Controller Test Class:

```
public class PromoteFooControllerTest extends SpringTest {

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response; 
    private AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter;
    private FooController fooController;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MockFooHelperSuccess")
    private FooHelper mockFooHelper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        adapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();

        HttpMessageConverter[] messageConverters = {new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter()};
        adapter.setMessageConverters(messageConverters); 
        /*Snipping boring request setup*/
    }   
    @Test 
    public void promoteFooTest() {
        System.out.println("Testing auto promote controller ");
        try {
            PromoteServiceResponse response = executePromoteController();
            assertTrue(response.getBrokerCenterURL() != null);
            assertTrue(response.getError() == null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Should have passed.");
        }
    }
    private PromoteServiceResponse executePromoteController() throws Exception {
        fooController = applicationContext.getBean(FooController.class);
        //Reflection happening here
        Field field = fooController.class.getField("fooHelper");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        //Next line does nothing!!!
        field.set(fooController, mockFooHelper);
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        adapter.handle(request, response, fooController);
        String fooServiceResponse = response.getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(fooServiceResponse); 
        return Miscellaneous.fromJSON(new TypeReference<PromoteServiceResponse>() {
            }, fooServiceResponse);
    }
}
```

Actual FooController implementation:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    FooHelper fooHelper;
}
```

SpringTest class for reference:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/default-servlet.xml")
public class SpringTest implements ApplicationContextAware {

    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    protected MockHttpServletRequest request;
    protected ServletRequestAttributes attributes;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext1)
            throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = applicationContext1;
    }

    protected void scopedBeansConfig() {
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) applicationContext
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        configurableBeanFactory.registerScope("session", new SessionScope());
        configurableBeanFactory.registerScope("request", new RequestScope());
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes);
    }
}
```

Mocked Helper:

```
@Component("MockFooHelperSuccess")
public class MockFooHelperSuccessImpl implements FooHelper {

    @Override
    public FooServiceResponse exceuteCreateFoo(String userName,
            String password, String callingSystem, String keepLocking,
            String updateToken, SourceFoo sourceFoo) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public FooSearchResponse executeSearchFoo(String userName,
            String password, FooSearchInput searchInput) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public FooServiceResponse executeRetrieveFoo(String userName,
            String password, String fooId, String integrationId,
            String system, Boolean lockBar) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public PromoteServiceResponse executePromoteFoo(String userName,
            String password, String fooId, Boolean systemReminder) {
        return PromoteServiceResponse.createSuccessResponse("testurl", "1-test");
    }

    @Override
    public PromoteValidateResponse executeValidateFoo(String employeeId,
            String personId, String userName, String password) {
        return PromoteValidateResponse.createSuccessResponse();
    }
}
```

default-servlet.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="beans-config.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="dozer-mapping-config.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="aop-config.xml" />

</beans:beans>
```

aop-config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="exceptionHandler" class="au.com.foosystem.exceptions.ExceptionHandlerImpl"/>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="exceptionHandler">
            <aop:after-returning pointcut="execution(* au.com.foosystem.controller..*(..))" returning="result" method="sendExceptionEmail"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

We eventually got it to work by changing a single line of code in the test class. We changed

```
fooController = applicationContext.getBean(FooController.class);
```

to

```
fooController = new FooController();
```

and the entire thing worked perfectly using both vanilla reflection and `ReflectionTestUtils`.

We also tried adding a getter/setter inside the controller <sub>(yes, we were that desperate)</sub> and manually set the instance of `FooHelper` inside the controller from the application context which also worked.

```
fooController = applicationContext.getBean(FooController.class);
fooController.setFooHelper(mockFooHelper);
response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
adapter.handle(request, response, fooController);
```

But our desire to get a test working was outweighed by our desire to NOT put a setter in a controller.

So our question is, why did Reflection fail to actually change the field instance. It was our understanding that Reflection is akin to the ultimate skeleton key for all Objects. We suspect that something in the Spring application context was either preventing the change from occurring or reverting the change at some point before the next line was run (because we had `println()` on the very next line.

Comment: What is in `aop-config.xml`?

Comment: A pointcut to call a method called `sendExceptionEmail` when any controller threw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your controller is in the package `au.com.foosystem.controller` which is advised through your AOP configuration here

```xml
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="exceptionHandler">
        <aop:after-returning pointcut="execution(* au.com.foosystem.controller..*(..))" returning="result" method="sendExceptionEmail"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

To apply this advice, Spring needs to proxy your controller bean. That is, it will generate an proxy object of a dynamic class which extends your `FooController` class. This behavior may differ from one version to another, but in this case it seems the proxy object actually refers to a real instance.

So through

```
fooController = applicationContext.getBean(FooController.class);
```

you get a reference to a proxy object which internally keeps a reference to the target actual `FooController` instance. Now because it is a dynamic subclass of `FooController` it also has a field of `FooHelper` through inheritance but it doesn't use it, it instead delegates all calls to the target `FooController` which maintains the `FooHelper` field.

Comment: See...  this is why you have 109k rep.... I bet that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: So I suppose if we remove the AOP config from the tests, we can check and see if that is what the problem is.

Comment: @JAmes That will definitely help, yes.